# Why my jquery data table is not working when I add a table data with a link?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, datatable

```
echo "<table id='table_id' class='display table table-hover table-inverse'>";

        echo "</thead>";
        echo "<tbody>";

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['last_update_time'] . "</td>";
```

When I add this row with a delete link, data table is not being applied to my table.

```
echo "<td><a href=delete.php?id=" . $row['id'] . ">Delete</a></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</tbody>";
        echo "</table>";
```

Without the particular line all works fine.

Please help.
TIA

Comment: What do you mean by *Without the particular line all works fine.*? What does work and what doesn't work? *Not working* and *working* is too general

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you please confirm that in your code, number of columns inside 'thead' are equal to number of columns inside 'tbody'. It should not mismatch the number of columns of both 'thead' and 'tbody'